# How to debug in pycharm when passing arguments on the command line?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I usually use breakpoints in pycharm  to debug my programme,as the picture shows
[debug picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICd5d.png)
Now my program is running with arguments passed from the command line (as shown below, using the parser module). I want to set breakpoints to debug it. What should I do?
[my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DVyT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Run --> Run configurations and there you can specify the command line arguments that you want to pass to your program.

Comment: Please consider accepting or upvoting the answer so that others know your issue has been resolved.